# When I return back to my Activity onCreate() function is not called

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an application and there i call second activity when it come back fist activity on create function is not called.. this problem occurred in android version 2.2 mobile. when i install 4.0 it work well... Please give some suggestions.
first activity --  call onStop then not in call on restart or on create 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

> I have an application and there i call second activity when it come
>   back fist activity on create function is not called.

=> While returning back to first activity, it will call `[onResume()][1]`.

And FYI, [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) calls only once when activity is starting.

Comment: this problem occurred in android version 2.2 mobile. when i install 4.0 it work well ?? Any ideas or guess!!!

Comment: @Paresh onResume() alos not calling

Answer (score 1):

If you want your closed Activity calls onCreate() after back, try to use method finish() this activity when you go to other Activity.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want `onCreate()` to be called again after pushing another activity on top of the stack, you should stop the current activity by calling `finish()`. And if you make statements like `onResume() also not calling`, prove it with code or something, because the [Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) is very clear about it, read the line below `figure 1`.

Comment: thanks... i am call another activity is browse  when  back form browser that time facing this problem...